# save and load uiswitch

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make an appointment form on the iPad and I'm having trouble with the `UISwitch`, I need to save its state and the later load it on another page, I have done this for a text field and a date picker but for some reason it doesn't work for the `UISwitch`. I am very new to this so any help would be appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)savedata:(id)sender; {

    NSString *savestring = _NameofResident.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *savestring1 = _NameofStudent.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults1 setObject:savestring1 forKey:@"savedstring1"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *savestring2 = _AppointmentTime.date;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults2 setObject:savestring2 forKey:@"savedstring2"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *savestring3 = _NextAppointmentTime.date;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults3 setObject:savestring3 forKey:@"savedstring3"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *savestring4 = _Confirmed.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults4 setObject:savestring4 forKey:@"savedstring4"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}


- (IBAction)loaddata:(id)sender; {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"];
    [_NameofResident setText:loadstring];

    NSString *loadstring1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring1"];
    [_NameofStudent setText:loadstring1];

    NSString *loadstring2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring2"];
    [_AppointmentTime setDate:loadstring2];

    NSString *loadstring3 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring3"];
    [_NextAppointmentTime setDate:loadstring3];

    NSString *loadstring4 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring4"];
    [_Confirmed setText:loadstring4];


}
```

As you can see I can both load and save the state for the names and times but I don't really know how I can add in a `UISwitch` to do this.

thanks for your help.

Comment: That code is crazy.  Why so many copies of `NSUserDefaults` and so many calls to `synchronize`?

Comment: Create just one instance of the NSUserDefaults and at the end calls synchronize

Comment: Please name your var starting with a lower case.

Comment: thank you for the help and sorry I'm very knew to this so I'm learning as i go along i understand now that i had to use a bool and i was making to many copies of user defaults and works fine now. thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the value of a UISwitch state, which is a BOOL, you can do 2 things :

- store the BOOL in an NSNumber ([NSNumber numberWithBool:myBool]) and save it with defaults setObject: method. But then, when retrieving the BOOL, you will have to do [defaults objectForKey:@"myKey"].boolValue
- store the BOOL itself with defaults setBool:forKey method. And retrieve it with defaults boolForKey method.

Moreover, I've seen you get the defaults many times and synchronize it many times. This is not necessary so I give you an example of what you could have done :

```
-(IBAction)savedata:(id)sender; {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *savestring = _NameofResident.text;
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"];

    NSString *savestring1 = _NameofStudent.text;
    [defaults setObject:savestring1 forKey:@"savedstring1"];

    NSString *savestring2 = _AppointmentTime.date;
    [defaults setObject:savestring2 forKey:@"savedstring2"];

    NSString *savestring3 = _NextAppointmentTime.date;
    [defaults setObject:savestring3 forKey:@"savedstring3"];

    NSString *savestring4 = _Confirmed.text;
    [defaults setObject:savestring4 forKey:@"savedstring4"];

    BOOL savebool5 = _Switch.isOn;
    [defaults setBool:savebool5 forKey:@"savedbool5"];

    [defaults synchronize];

}


- (IBAction)loaddata:(id)sender; {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"];
    [_NameofResident setText:loadstring];

    NSString *loadstring1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring1"];
    [_NameofStudent setText:loadstring1];

    NSString *loadstring2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring2"];
    [_AppointmentTime setDate:loadstring2];

    NSString *loadstring3 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring3"];
    [_NextAppointmentTime setDate:loadstring3];

    NSString *loadstring4 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring4"];
    [_Confirmed setText:loadstring4];

    BOOL loadBool5 = [defaults boolForKey:@"savedbool5"];
    [_Switch setOn:loadBool5];
}
```

Comment: will this still save and load the state i left it in?

Comment: perfect it works thank you very much you have been a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem the following way:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//


#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.mySwitch.on forKey:@"SwitchState"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mySwitch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];

}

@end
```

Happy programming !